# Check if the execution is running in debug mode

Tags: google-apps-script, environment

Is there a way to check if Google Apps Script is running in debug mode ?

For an example, I have a script for which I use `prompt` but, in debug mode, I want to set predefined values for these prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try debugging myfunc() with debugMyFunc();

```
function debugMyFunc() {
  myfunc('debug');
}

function myfunc(mode) {
  var mode=mode||'run';
}
```

Comment: Good idea ! I've thinking to use a boolean value `var debug = true` but there is a "danger" to not think to update the variable, following the context (executed from the spreadsheet or via the debugger)...
I think your solution is better.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

If you are looking for an analog of a debug environment, then no, there is no dedicated way - the only mode is production (although some services like [`CardService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card#printJson()) and [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl,-params) do have debug methods).

**Workaround**

The closest thing to an environment would be using `PropertiesService` to store, update and retrieve script / user properties. You can persist the settings per user or, which is closer to what an environment variable is, per script and use them as needed.

Therefore, to check whether you run in a debug mode, you can load the property from store (preferrably at startup to reduce property reads / writes), check for something like `mode`, and then pass the result around + change and persist as needed.

A simple example:

```
/**
 * @returns {object}
 */
function getEnvironment() {
  const store = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const env = JSON.parse(store.getProperty("env") || "{}");

  env.Modes = Object.freeze({
    Debug : 1,
    Prod : 2
  });

  return env;
}
```

Then, in your main script:

```
function onOpen() {

  let { mode, Modes } = getEnvironment();

  if(mode === Modes.Debug) {
    //do something in debug
  }

  mode = Modes.Prod;

  //continue in production
}
```

**References**

1. `PropertiesService` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)