# Testing whether script is being run by interactive debugger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a project that reads a Google Sheets spreadsheet and maintains a summary of contents in another sheet.  All the hooks are in place to run as needed (daily, weekly, whatever), starting where it last left off, and the unprocessed rows will affect the summary.

In case the summary sheet ever needs to be wiped out and all data reprocessed, I have added a menu option for reinitialization.  Within that reinitialization function there is  dialog:

```
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var result = ui.alert(
          "Please confirm"
        , "This will completely wipe out the summary data and start over, and may require many executions in order to catch up.  Are you sure you want to do this?"
        , ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
          );
    if (result == ui.Button.NO) {
        ui.alert("Good thing I asked!");
        return;
        }
```

(This happens only when there are design changes to the summary.)

If I am running this process in the scripts debugger, the process dies with the message:

```
Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.
```

So I would like to avoid that part of the code when debugging.  How can I determine if the script is being run in that mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

I guess a straightforward solution would be to [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) the error.

- If you want to check for a **specific** error message, you can use the `error` property `message` which returns the error as a string.
- If the error message is the **expected** error, namely:
  `Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context` then **continue** with the rest of the code.
- If the error is something else (within the `try` statement) then `throw` that **unexpected** error and **stop** the script.

### Workaround Solution 1:

```
   try {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var result = ui.alert(
          "Please confirm"
        , "This will completely wipe out the summary data and start over, and may require many executions in order to catch up.  Are you sure you want to do this?"
        , ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
          );
    if (result == ui.Button.NO) {
        ui.alert("Good thing I asked!");
        return;
        }       
   }
   catch(e){
      if(e.message=="Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context"){
      console.log("the expected error occured, everything is fine"); // the expected error occured, continue
      }
      else{throw e}; // throw the unexpected error and stop the script
   }
   
   // continue with the rest of the code with no issues
```

### Workaround Solution 2:

I just stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62177393/11225291) which might work for you. Essentially you can introduce a `"debug"` parameter within a function that encloses the "problematic" code and execute this code depending the `"debug"` parameter. Still that is a workaround solution which needs some manual intervention, therefore I would recommend the first solution of this answer which allows you to have full control of the error messages.

Comment: This is a fairly good idea, but I'd like to ensure the catch occurred for the right reason.  (It's never happened to me, of course, ( :P ) but conceivably a bug could be introduced to the code.)

Comment: @Dennis see my updated answer with the explanation. Essentially, you can catch this exact particular error. If the expected error occurs then continue with your code. If something else occurs (within the try statement) `throw` it in the console and stop the script. So you are 100% sure that you are catching this particular specific error message. (No bug at all).

Comment: Yes, your solution 1 will work for me.  I am trying to avoid manual human-memory-driven solutions, as you imply.  In the end, we hope that the next debug session will be the last, right?  So the exception test is quick, easy, and probably quite foolproof.  Thanks so much for your obvious effort here.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based completely on @Marios' answer, I have created the following function to share in the event someone else runs into this problem.  Note that the error message would be different in some other language.

To use it, copy/paste the getYesNo function below into your code.  Then you can reference it as such:

```
if (getYesNo("It's wet down there", "Are you sure you want to jump off of this bridge?", false)) {
    jump();
    }
```

In the event that the dialog cannot be displayed, the default value will be returned.
Here's the code:

```
function getYesNo(shorMessage, longMessage, defaultResult) {

    // We'll prompt the user if we can.  But in some instances (for example in a batch execution or a debug session)
    // we cannot do that.  If we run across that problem, we'll return the default value.

    var rtnValue = defaultResult;
    try {
          var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

          var result = ui.alert(
                shortMessage
              , longMessage
              , ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
                );
          if (result == ui.Button.NO) rtnValue = false;
          else                        rtnValue = true;
          }
    catch(e) {
          if (e.message.indexOf("Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.") >= 0) {
                console.log("Expected error about dialog was received.  All is well: "
                          + e.message)
                           );
                }
          else throw e;
          }
    return rtnValue
    }
```

Thanks @Marios

Comment: You are welcome! thanks for the answer too :)